# Maximum number of acute triangles

Tags: geometry, contest-math, combinatorial-geometry

Given $n$ points on the plane, no three of which are collinear, what is the maximum number of acute triangles formed by them?

[Source: Based on Hungarian competition problem]

Comment: I'd guess the optimal placement would be to have the points evenly distributed on a circle, but I'm not certain. That would at least give you a pretty good lower bound.

Comment: @Arthur, for $n=12$ a better solution is to place one point in the center of a circle and other points distributed on the circle. Then you have $52$ acute triangles instead of $20$ in your solution. Am i correct?

Comment: [An upper bound](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/745860/bound-the-number-of-acute-angled-triangles?rq=1)